Are Kotlin extension methods a good example of the Open/Closed Principle?
The Open/Closed Principle is sometimes hard to grasp but it seems to me that Kotlin extension methods are a prime example because they allow classes to remain closed to modification but open to extension.
Am I understanding the principle correctly?

A similar mechanism in C# is considered as such. Reading up on the Kotlin ways of doing it, it seems to apply as well. I also found an older discussion on this topic for Kotlin.

I think it is debatable. Since an extension function cannot read private or protected members, it’s really just syntactic sugar for interacting with an instance of a class, like any other function that is not part of the class. But yes, this question is a duplicate of the one linked above.

Reading the early writings about that principle, it seems to me they were thinking specifically about subclassing and the ability to create a class that could be substituted for the parent and still work because it didn’t remove parent behaviors. With an extension function you are not creating something new or creating a substitute with additional features. You are just interacting with what already exists.

In my eyes general idea behind OCP is how to modify (extend) software behavior without rewriting it much and do not break existing functionalities.
Kotlin's extensions extend capabilities of a type however it is resolved statically, there is no dynamic function dispatch. In other words it's just a handy form to pack code that somehow relates to receiver.
A textbook example of OCP is polymorphism. It gives ability to modify software behavior simply adding a new implementation of polymorphic type and replace existing one.
an everyday example is passing a callback:
fun <T, R> f(a: String, callback: (T) -> R) {}

Via callback we can modify function behavior but cannot change its logic. So it is open to extend but closed to changes.
